# Is it possible to have 2 UserDetailsService (one for each WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need 2 login pages, and both should lookup login information from a database. The way I understand it, that means:

1. I need 2 classes that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
2. Since I need to look up information from a database (2 different tables) I need 2 classes that implements UserDetailsService.

I've tried to do this, but when I have two Beans with classes that implements UserDetailsService, it looks like neither is used (I also tried to only use a UserDetailsService in one of the Security classes, and had both UserDetailsServices defined). Each class looks like this:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String user) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      /* ..... */
    }
}
```

And then I autowire in a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /* filter */
    }

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;    
}
```

(The other WebSecurityConfigureAdapter has the @Order(1) annotation)

Comment: Could you clarify what is different about the two login pages and the two user tables? I am wondering if distinguishing users by roles would be an alternative way to cover your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that adding this to the security class helped:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
}
```

(It seems like it couldn't automatically select the Autowired one in the same security class, if there are more than one UserDetailsService)